# Simplest way to redirect a mobile phone away from a website with Flash

Tags: html, flash

Very simply put, I have a Flash heavy website. I also have a PDF version of the information on the website. I want to add determine the browser (or platform) requesting the site and if it is a mobile device (or Flash unsupported device, i.e. iPhone or iPad) redirect the user to the PDF.

I think it should be some simple Javascript, I just have never dealt with needing this behavior from a site before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used either of these methods myself, but here are two examples I found after a quick search:

http://www.hackingethics.com/blog/2011/02/06/how-to-redirect-your-website-to-mobile-website-on-mobile-devices-by-javascript/
This one tests whether the navigator is one of several mobile types, and then redirects.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/
This one has a method of testing the screen size. If the screen is small enough to be mobile, it redirects the browser to the mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to use a server side check like PHP, because most mobile browsers do not support javascript. Check if the user agent is mobile then redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Since mobile devices (or at least tablets) are starting to support Flash, I wouldn't blanket reject anything with a "Mobile" in the query string.  Instead, I would recommend feature checking.  Since mobile browsers have limited bandwidth, charge for data transferred, and may not support PDF's, I would also recommend making the navigation to the PDF optional.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"]) {
        if(confirm('Your browser does not support flash?  Would you like ' +
                   'view the PDF version? (25kB)')) {
            location.replace('static_file.pdf');
        } else {
            // Show some "We're sorry" content.
        }
    }
</script>
<noscript>
    <p>This requires Flash.  <a href="static_file.pdf">Click here to 
    view the PDF version. (25kB)</a></p>
</noscript>
```